# R &R :stage 4: Create and train the ranker,

Tags: python

I followed the [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/get_start.shtml) for Retrieve & Rank, I did stage 1,2 and 3, however I couldn't finish stage 4: Create and train the ranker, When ever I followed the steps listed in stage 4, I received the following error message:

```
python: can't open file './train.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

Please note that the `train.py` file was downloaded and saved on my laptop, my question "what I did wrong?"

Answer (score 0):

Python is telling you it can't find the script `train.py` in the current working directory.  Did you skip this step in the [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/get_start.shtml)?

> Navigate to the downloaded train.py script.

This means `cd` to the same directory as the file.